# Throw a user defined exception when the age is not between the range

Tags: java, if-statement, constructor, exception, try-catch

I have created a `class Student` with attributes: `rno, age, name, course` and I have defined a paramerized contructor. I want to throw an exception when `age` is not between 15 and 21. I have initialized `age` as 27 but it is not going into the if condition. Do you have an idea why that is?

```
   class Age extends Exception
   {
   Age(String str)
   {
    super(str);
   }
  }

  public class Student
  {
   int rno,age;
   String name,course;

   Student(int r,int a,String n,String c) 
   { 
    rno=r;
    age=a;
    name=n;
    course=c;
   }

   public void display()
   { 
    try
      {
       if(age<=15 && age>=21)
          throw new Age("Not accepted");
       else 
        System.out.println("Name:"+name);
        System.out.println("Rno:"+rno);
        System.out.println("Age:"+age);
        System.out.println("Course:"+course);
        System.out.println("...........");
      }

   catch(Age a)
    {
       System.out.println(""+a);
    }
   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    Student s1=new Student(1,26,"ABC","Java");
    Student s2=new Student(2,17,"XYZ","C++");
    s1.display();
    s2.display();
   }
  }

  Output
   Name:ABC
  Rno:1
  Age:26
  Course:Java
  ...........
  Name:XYZ
  Rno:2
  Age:17
  Course:C++
  ...........
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is with statement `if(age<=15 && age>=21)` - age will never be at the same time lower than 15 and greater than 21.

You have `&&` which means AND in bool logic, you need to change it to `||` which means OR.

Comment: Good answer. You should rename class `Age` to `AgeException` to make it clear that that class is an Exception class

Answer (score 2):

```
if(age<=15 || age>=21)
```

This should be the statement in this condition check. As both the conditions can't be true in any case.